# Cache headers not sent to client

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, caching, laravel

A site I'm building serves a lot of images in a gallery. I want to utilize browser cache capabilities for these images. My backend is based on the principals of REST, and I'm using a controller method to serve images.

```
// check if the client validating cache and if it is current
$ifModified = Request::header('If-Modified-Since');
if (isset($ifModified) && (strtotime($ifModified) == filemtime($filePath . $fileName))) {
    // cache IS current, respond 304
    header('HTTP/1.0 304 Not Modified');
    exit();
} else {
    return new BinaryFileResponse(readfile($filePath . $fileName), 200,
        array(
            'Content-Type' => 'image/jpeg', // Guessing probably all jpegs.
            'Content-Transfer-Encoding' => 'binary',
            'Content-Disposition' => 'inline; filename="' . $fileName . '"',
            'Content-Length' => filesize($filePath . $fileName),
            'Expires' => date(DATE_RFC822, strtotime("+2 days")),
            'Last-Modified' => date(DATE_RFC822, \Illuminate\Support\Facades\File::lastModified($filePath . $fileName)),
            'Cache-Control' => 'public, max-age=10800, pre-check=10800',
            'Pragma' => 'public',
        ), true, 'inline');
}
```

When running this through my localhost, the response headers are:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 05 May 2014 18:12:56 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.4 (Win64) PHP/5.4.12
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.12
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-Disposition: inline; filename="2930..jpg"
Content-Length: 17080
Expires: Wed, 07 May 14 18:12:57 +0000
Cache-Control: max-age=10800, pre-check=10800, public
Last-Modified: Mon, 05 May 14 11:43:08 +0000
Pragma: public
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-UA-Compatible: IE=edge,chrome=1
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=97
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: image/jpeg
```

When running the site through my hosting provider, the response headers are:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 05 May 2014 18:29:24 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.27 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.27 OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips mod_bwlimited/1.4
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.27
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Expires: Mon, 05 May 2014 18:29:24 GMT
X-UA-Compatible: IE=edge,chrome=1
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=96
Connection: Keep-Alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
```

I'm using a .htaccess file wihch is identical on both localhost and my hosting provider. Besides the differences in  Apache and PHP versions, I'm guessing that this might be a server configuration issue. What do I look for in order to find out why the backend running on the host is not transmitting the correct headers to the client?

Comment: You are aware that sending these headers alone will not do the full job, right? You will also have to answer _conditional_ GET requests accordingly.

Comment: Not sure what you are pointing at... I AM checking if 'If-Modified-Since' request headers are present, and quickly return a 304 NOT MODIFIED if file has not changed. I just did not include that piece of the code. Is this what you mean?

Comment: I've updated the response method above to reflect that I'm also handling If-Modified-Since request headers

Comment: Yes, that’s what I meant. If you’ve already taken care of that, good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad. I'm such a smurf!

This code works:

```
// check if the client validating cache and if it is current
$ifModified = Request::header('If-Modified-Since');
if (isset($ifModified) && (strtotime($ifModified) == filemtime($filePath . $fileName))) {
    // cache IS current, respond 304
    header('HTTP/1.0 304 Not Modified');
    exit();
} else {
    return new BinaryFileResponse($filePath . $fileName, 200,
        array(
            'Content-Type' => 'image/jpeg', // Guessing probably all jpegs.
            'Content-Transfer-Encoding' => 'binary',
            'Content-Disposition' => 'inline; filename="' . $fileName . '"',
            'Content-Length' => filesize($filePath . $fileName),
            'Expires' => date(DATE_RFC822, strtotime("+2 days")),
            'Last-Modified' => date(DATE_RFC822, \Illuminate\Support\Facades\File::lastModified($filePath . $fileName)),
            'Cache-Control' => 'public, max-age=10800, pre-check=10800',
            'Pragma' => 'public',
        ), true, 'inline');
}
```

Since I'm returning a Binary **File** Response, I of course should not read the file before handing it over. The response constructor expects a file name, not the data. 
Anyway, this uncovered that there were never any problems with the response headers at all.

The response failed and I got the headers accordingly. But since I read in the data from the image file, the data went along as the body of the request anyway. Which was the reason I did not catch the error.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this question: [Cannot set Cache-Control in Laravel 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22439907/cannot-set-cache-control-in-laravel-4)

They suggest using `BinaryFileResponse` as you are, but they're using the actual methods of that class to set the various settings. Perhaps it's an issue with parsing the values you're passing.

Comment: But why does my localhost parse the values fine and not my hosting provider? Based on the fact that the headers actually ARE sent when running on localhost, I don't think that this could be a Laravel bug. I'm using the same version of the framework in both instances...

Comment: That is very strange. Perhaps it's a PHP setting or a host setting. I'll look further into it for you.